# Render an external webpage inside a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Not sure if this has been answered, but is there a way to render an external website inside a React application?

For example, I want to lay components on top of google.com. Is there a module to do this in ReactJS?

Comment: The only way to load a website "inside" another is via `<iframe>`s. And some websites (including Google) try to detect and prevent that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, via iFrames it is possible to load webpages inside of other webpages, but it breaks the basic rule: "one document per URL". This type of project is better handled by an extension in the browser rather than a website.

React JS is capable of functioning as your view engine for a Chrome extension. So you may still use that language if you desire.

Comment: The project I was asking this for is exactly that - a ReactJS chrome extension. Thank you very much for your answer!